# Close and refresh VF button

Tags: visualforce

I've developed a Visualforce button that callout an external Webservice and fills object fields with the obtained information.

I cant find the way to create button to close the VF page and refresh the Object that was modified and refresh the page to show the changes.

Is this possible? What can I try to achieve this?

***EDIT***

Visualforce button.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="EquifaxEmpresaController" action="{!consultaEmpresa}">
   <input type="hidden" value="{!account.Equifax__c}"></input>   

<apex:pageBlock >

  <apex:form >
  {!theJSON}
   </apex:form>

  </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

Extension Class

```
public class EquifaxEmpresaController {

    private final Account acct;
    public EquifaxEmpresa theEmpresa {get;set;}
    public String theJSON {get;set;}
    public String aux {get;set;}

    public EquifaxEmpresaController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
        this.acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
   }

    public void consultaEmpresa(){

        string msj = '{'+
                     '"NroDocumento":"'+acct.Equifax__c+'",'+
                     '"Consulta":"Empresa"'+
                     '}';

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('some endpoint here');
        req.setBody(msj);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        req.setTimeout(12000);

        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();

        res = Http.send(req);
        if(res.getStatusCode() == 200){
            String body = res.getBody();
            theEmpresa = EquifaxEmpresa.parse(body);
            Account tempAcct = [select id, BC_IE_Razon_Social__c from account where id =: acct.Id];

            tempAcct.BC_IE_Razon_Social__c = theEmpresa.Empresa[0].RazonSocial;
            tempAcct.Name = theEmpresa.Empresa[0].NombreComercial;
            tempAcct.BC_IE_Tipo_de_Contribuyente__c = theEmpresa.Empresa[0].TipoContribuyente;
            tempAcct.BC_IE_Estado_de_Contribuyente__c = theEmpresa.Empresa[0].EstadoContribuyente;
            tempAcct.BC_IE_Condicion_Contribuyente__c = theEmpresa.Empresa[0].CondicionContribuyente;
            tempAcct.BC_IE_Razon_Dependencia__c = theEmpresa.Empresa[0].Dependencia;
            tempAcct.BC_IE_Codigo_CIIU__c = theEmpresa.Empresa[0].CodigoCIIU;
            tempAcct.BC_IE_Descripcion_CIIU__c = theEmpresa.Empresa[0].DescripcionCIIU;
            tempAcct.BC_IE_Inicio_Actividades__c = theEmpresa.Empresa[0].InicioActividades;
            tempAcct.BC_IE_Actividad_Comercio_Exterior__c = theEmpresa.Empresa[0].ActividadComercioExterior;
            tempAcct.BC_IE_Numero_Trabajadores__c = theEmpresa.Empresa[0].NumeroTrabajadores;

            update tempAcct;

            theJSON = 'Datos correctamente insertados, puede cerrar esta ventana.';

        }else{
            theJSON = 'Error :'+res.getBody()+' '+res.getStatusCode();
        }

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes it can be done. The how would depend on your implementation. Would be very helpful if you could share the relevant code, otherwise we are just guessing

Comment: I'll edit, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to return back to the account record simply add this to your method

```
public PageReference consultaEmpresa(){

    return new PageReference('/' + acct.Id);

}
```

You can remove `theJSON` from the page and the controller as it will never be shown

In case you need to setRedirect which you should not

```
public PageReference consultaEmpresa(){

        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/' + acct.Id);
        pr.setRedirect(true);
        return pr;

    }
```

Comment: i dont need a button that method to executes the function, because is executing when the page is loaded, what I need is a button that returns to the object and refresh with changes

Comment: @ÓscarLobos doh. Missed the action parameter. Check updated answer

Comment: this return inside the consultaEmpresa method? o should i create a new method for the PageReference? (consultaEmpresa() is a public void)

Comment: @ÓscarLobos add the return at the END of the consultaEmpresa method. Make sure to update the return type. When it is done executing it will return you to the account page

Comment: thanks @Eric, this worked, but there is anyway to refresh and show the changes when It went back to the pageReference?

Comment: @ÓscarLobos If the changes are on the account record they should be there so long as your method populated the field as expected. I will add the setRedirect example for you to try as well but it should not be needed unless I am forgetting the basics

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104618/discussion-between-oscar-lobos-and-eric).